# Getting raw multitouch data with libinput

Tags: c, linux, multi-touch

I'd like to get the raw multitouch data from my touchpad in order to.

I've tried using [libevdev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50268899/reading-multitouch-using-libevdev) but my success was limited and I couldn't do what I wanted. I found out about libinput which might be more abstracted, and found out how to use it to automatically get the gestures (for example using `libinput-debug-events`) but I find them limited and would like to get the raw input (with each finger's movement).

Is there any way to do this with libinput, or not?

I couldn't find any helpful documentation: I found [this one](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/group__event__touch.html) but couldn't find any example or route to follow. Actually, I think that I could make myself a way through my problems if I understood how to use these functions, but it's far from clear, and I'm getting in a lot of trouble installing libinput itself (for example, commands like `libinput debug-gui` aren't recognized by my system).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Don't know if this helps or not, but on my distro (Ubuntu) I installed libinput-tools.

```
sudo libinput debug-gui
```

Also gives me an error:

*debug-gui is not a libinput command or not installed.*

However,

```
sudo libinput debug-events
```

will print out events in the terminal just fine.

Comment: For me it doesn't log raw data but rather high-level events, without the exact coordinates for each finger.